# Custom field values are not importing with Features

Tags: drush, features

I would like to export example data(nodes) in feature for others to kick start some reusable module that i developed. The example data contains nodes with custom fields. The problem is that while nodes and default field values(title, body) are importing the values for the custom fields are not. I am new to features. I must be doing something wrong.

For the example data I have selected the nodes, field bases, field instances and rest of the dependencies detected, but this is not export/import the custom field values. I am guess i have to select some more StrongArm variable values since these custom field instances are shared across multiple nodes? if so, how do i detect the dependent variables to particular node instance?...strongarm does not provide any drush command for that purpose...Any help is much appreciated

p.s. Are you using features for exporting/importing Sample Data of you custom module? I may have taken the wrong approach

Features: 7.x-2.0,
uuid_features: 7.x-1.0-alpha3,
strongarm: 7.x-2.0,
Drupal: 7.26

Comment: I am seeing that in the exported feature(module_name.features.uuid_node.inc) the Taxonomy Term Ids(tid) are not in the UUID format. I am not sure why it is saving in TID instead UUID? ...will continue look into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, the custom fields of nodes that reference to Taxonomy elements did not export/import via features. The reason is that Taxonomy term references(tid) are stored by ID instead of UUID with stable version of uuid_features and uuid as of Feb, 2014

The solution was to use dev version 7.x-1.x-dev for uuid as well as uuid_feature module. This will export/import custom fields (term reference) into UUID instead ID that solved the problem